# ICollectionView multiple filter

Tags: c#

So I have a fitler TextBox where I want to search for different type of docs in a grid the code where I have different type of columns such as: Date,DocId,ClientId.
For a search I write on a filter Textbox something like that `DocId:2002` and It just work fine but when I try to make a multiple search for example `DocId:2002 ClientId:201` It doesnt search because of the return it just does an infinite loop.

```cs
private void TextBoxFilter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches((sender as TextBox).Text, pattern, options))
      {
        if (m.Value != "")
        {
          Func<String, String> untilSlash = (s) => { return filters[re.Match(s).Groups[1].ToString()] = re.Match(s).Groups[2].ToString(); };
          untilSlash(m.Value);
        }
      }
      ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.DataGridDocList.ItemsSource);
      if (filters.Count == 0)
      {
        cv.Filter = null;
      }
      else
      {
        cv.Filter = o =>
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < filters.Count; i++)
          {

            if (filters.ElementAt(i).Key == "Date")
            {
              if (DateVerify.Match(filters.ElementAt(i).Value).Success)
              {
                return (o as Document).DateCreated < Convert.ToDateTime(DateVerify.Match(filters.ElementAt(i).Value).Groups[1].ToString()) && (o as Document).DateCreated > Convert.ToDateTime(DateVerify.Match(filters.ElementAt(i).Value).Groups[2].ToString());
              }
              else
              {
                var dateString = (o as Document).DateCreated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                return dateString.Contains(DateVerify.Match(filters.ElementAt(i).Value).Groups[1].ToString());
              }
            }
            if (filters.ElementAt(i).Key == "DocId")
            {
              return (o as Document).DocumentId.ToString().Contains(filters.ElementAt(i).Value);
            }
            if (filters.ElementAt(i).Key == "ClientId")
            {
              return (o as Document).ClientId.ToUpper().Contains(filters.ElementAt(i).Value.ToUpper());
            }
          }
          return false;
        };
        filters.Clear();
      }
    }
```

So my question is how can I do an big search with all the filters at one time?
Manually I can add them 1 by 1 and it will be something like search1 && search2 && search3 but It will take too much time and It's probably not the best solution

Comment: Are you able to upload the full code, so I can re-create the issue?

Comment: I can't give you the full code because you won't have the access to the db's. But if you can be more specific about what you need, I can edit

Comment: In your code, you have variables/methods: filters, DateVerify, Document, re - I'm not sure what these are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of building up the predicate. However my suggestion is to keep it simple and just create one method that returns **true** or **false**. *It's good practice to only return once in a method*.

The code below if for illustration purposes (as I'm unable to test it):

```
ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.DataGridDocList.ItemsSource);

if (filters.Any())
{
    cv.Filter = new Predicate<object>(PredicateFilter);
}
else
{
    cv.Filter = null;
}
```

Then Predicate method to filter results:

```
public bool PredicateFilter(object docObj)
{
    Document doc = docObj as Document;

    var response = new List<bool>();    

    for (int i = 0; i < filters.Count; i++)
    {
        if (filters.ElementAt(i).Key == "Date")
        {
            if (DateVerify.Match(filters.ElementAt(i).Value).Success)
            {
                response.Add(doc.DateCreated < Convert.ToDateTime(DateVerify.Match(filters.ElementAt(i).Value).Groups[1].ToString()) && doc.DateCreated > Convert.ToDateTime(DateVerify.Match(filters.ElementAt(i).Value).Groups[2].ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                var dateString = doc.DateCreated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                response.Add(dateString.Contains(DateVerify.Match(filters.ElementAt(i).Value).Groups[1].ToString()));
            }
        }
        else if (filters.ElementAt(i).Key == "DocId")
        {
            response.Add(doc.DocumentId.ToString().Contains(filters.ElementAt(i).Value));
        }
        else if (filters.ElementAt(i).Key == "ClientId")
        {
            response.Add(doc.ClientId.ToUpper().Contains(filters.ElementAt(i).Value.ToUpper()));
        }
    }
            
    return response.All(m => m); // if all filters came back with true, return 1 response of true else false.
}
```